# T-SQL CASE WHEN statement not working with between

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, case

So I am stuck on this where statement of mine.  Each individual case runs fine in the where clause but when i try and wrap it up in a case when statement it breaks on me.  Is there an issue with using the between statement in a case when statement? Below is the code.  If there is any thoughts please share!

The logic in English is there is a check box on a ssrs form.  so box can either be 1 or 0 and depending on the value i will execute either where statement.

```
WHERE (CASE @box
WHEN 1 THEN (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL) 
ELSE 0 THEN (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL 
AND NOT  CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL AND CheckReg.CheckDate IS NOT NULL)
END)
```

Also if anyone knows a better solution then my logic above please let me know.  I am using Microsoft sql sever

Comment: after the `THEN` there's supposed to be an expression returning some value, not another logical comparison

Comment: what is `AND NOT  CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL AND CheckReg.CheckDate IS NOT NULL` supposed to do?

Comment: the and not part actually works it was my way of making an exclusive or.  To either get all nulls or all dates within range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `OR`

```
WHERE
  (@box = 1 AND (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL))
  OR
  (@box = 0 AND (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL 
                AND NOT CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL AND CheckReg.CheckDate IS NOT NULL))
```

or you can combine condition in `WHEN` part and compare with `THEN`:

```
WHERE 
   (CASE
     WHEN @box = 1 AND (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL)
     THEN 1
     WHEN @box = 0 AND (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL 
                        AND NOT CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL AND CheckReg.CheckDate IS NOT NULL)
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END
  ) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `CASE` like that - `CASE` is for conditional assignment, not for conditional logic.  You need to separate each of the logical flows as such:

```
WHERE 
(
    @box = 1 
    AND (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL) 
)
OR
(
    @box = 0
    AND (CheckReg.CheckDate BETWEEN @ChkStartDate and @ChkEndDate OR CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL )
    AND NOT (CheckReg.CheckDate IS NULL AND CheckReg.CheckDate IS NOT NULL)
)
```

Comment: This answer was also correct so thank you.  I believe i can only check one answer so i went with first one in.  I really appreciate the help -Peter